# Final checklist before releasing app

Tags: android, google-play

I've prepared my app for release and I just have a few questions before I submit regarding the submission process.I have a couple seam-to-be violations with the rules. Here are my questions. Am i allowed to modify the Back buttons behavior to do nothing when it is pressed? Right now the app has landscape mode disabled, is this allowed? How stringent are they with their Core App Quality Guidelines? Do i have to make it able to be installed on External Storage if its a simple 2d game?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am i allowed to modify the Back buttons behavior to do nothing when it is pressed?

Yes.

> Right now the app has landscape mode disabled, is this allowed?

Yes.

> How stringent are they with their Core App Quality Guidelines?

Google does not check your app after you submit it (like Apple does). So basically you are free to design and develop everything, as long as it does not violate the terms and conditions of the play store.

> Do i have to make it able to be installed on External Storage if its a simple 2d game?

No, you don't have to.

Comment: simple and neatly exaplained. But is overriding the back button a case of good design. I seem to get different views from so users. I was suggested by warren faith not to do so as it is a bad design.

Comment: @Raghunandan MikeT didn't ask weather it is a good design or not, he only asked weather this is allowed or not. It iS allowed, but in most cases it is in fact not really user friendly :)

Comment: i understand the question was different. i do agree its not user friendly. i asked it for my own clarification as i seem to see a lot of different views on this on SO. thanks for you time explaining.

Comment: @Raghunandan Ah ok, sorry misunderstood it then. IMO it *is* a bad design in most cases, since the user expects the app to close itself or go back, but instead the app acts different. Therefore this is considered to be not really user friendly. There might be some exceptions where you might want to consider overriding the back button though. In games particular.

Comment: @Raghunandan For example I own a Nexus 4 and it has a on screen keyboard. Sometimes I accidentally press the back button while playing a game (this can happen very easily if you are deeply involved in that game and are not paying attention to anything else). In this case it might be better to display a pause screen rather than immediately finishing the Activity, since you will probably loose your entire game state. This is one of the only few reasons to override the back button.

Comment: yes i have seen it in many games. your explanation cleared my confusion coz i know overriding back button functionality is bad and i see many suggesting the same on SO and i do comment on those. Well know its more clearer. i gonna mark this for future reference. Thank you for your nice and neat explanation.

Comment: When you ask if something is allowed, yes, all of those things are allowed, but they will have consequences in terms of not just the user experience, but also your app's rankings in Google Play search results.  And an app that violates design guidelines is very unlikely to ever be featured.  So you won't be prevented from doing these things, but somebody may notice them and that may limit your app's exposure on the store.